# How to denote an iterated integral with respect to a set of variables?

Tags: integration, notation, iterated-integrals

Let $x := (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector of states with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ dimensions in the space of real numbers and let $f, g : \mathbb{R}^n \to [0, 1]$ be some differentiable functions.

Consider the expression:
$$
L := \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x) dx.
$$

Observe that one iteration of the summation in $L$ with $i = 1$ is:
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}f(x) dx_1 \right] d(x_2, \dots, x_n).
$$

Could $L$ then be expressed as the following?
$$
L = \sum_{i=1}^n \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \left[\int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x)dx_i\right]\prod_{j \neq i}^n dx_j
$$

Alternatively, if using an index set $I = \{1, \dots, n\} \subset \mathbb{N}$, would the following be better?
$$
L = \sum_{i \in I} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \left[ \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x) dx_i \right] \prod_{j \in I \setminus \{i\}} dx_j
$$

Comment: I think even the function $L(x)$ is not well-defined for you take $x$ to be the variable of integrand but it also appears in $L(x)$. So what does $x$ mean?

Comment: Are those meant to be indefinite integrals?

Comment: @LucelliaKassel, L is a constant (updated). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @eyeballfrog, they are integrals over $[-\infty, \infty]$ for each dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Oh I see. If you just wanna know whether this is a legal expression, then I think it's OK if you make some explanations on what your notation means. But logically you are using Fubini' theorem so your statement holds only when Fubini's theorem applies. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

Comment: @LucelliaKassel, thanks. Yes, I realize now that my expression requires Fubini's theorem to hold. My question now is: is the produce of $dx_j$ legal? Or does that violate something about differentials?